# Why I do not have image files when install magento community version 2.1.5?

Tags: magento2, installation

I followed the tutorial (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html), but it doesn't have any images under `.....\pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\images\`
**Why? and how to solve it?**

I have other images, only do not have logo? svg?[image]

Comment: run `setup:static-content:deploy` command and then check !!! make sure your `var` and `pub` directory have writable permission

Comment: Where and how to run that command? How to make sure those two directories have writable permission. Please see my updated edit. I have other images, I only do not have logo svg images

Comment: okay !! if you dont have logo image only !! then check logo is uploaded or not from backend !!! `go to - >content->design configuration -> edit your default layout -> header settings -> logo upload` if not then upload it and click on save !!!!! you can also check your browser console !! logo not found error is there or not

Comment: Hi Manthan, when I click 'content' in admin panel, it does not have any reaction. Only 'dashboard' have reaction, others like 'sales' do not have any reaction. Why? Is it common for other people that cannot load svg logo but can load images?

Comment: @AngularFan, follow the below steps first and than check again and if you are using the default luma theme than you don't need to upload logo in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` and replace it with `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

After that remove below directories:

1. Remove `var/cache`
2. Remove `var/composer_home`
3. Remove `var/generation`
4. Remove `var/page_cache`
5. Remove `var/view_preprocessed`
6. run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Hope this help!!!!